# $\lim (3^n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ anyone?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} (3^n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}} = ?$

The help tip says I should use squeeze theorem but somehow still can't figure it out :/

Comment: Limit as n approaches what?

Comment: n approached infinity

Answer (score 2):

If it's infinity you can use $3^n\leq 3^n+1\leq 3^{n+1}$ ie the sandwich theorem